# How can I combine DeferredResult with ListenableFuture list?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, guava, future

I have a list of Guava `ListenableFuture` instances and Spring `DeferredResult`. I want to set the result for the first successful future in the list or if timeout didn't expire yet to get a successful result from all futures. Here is my try:

```
DeferredResult<String> foo() {
    DeferredResult<String> result = new DeferredResult<>(3000L);

    List<String> resps = newArrayList();
    List<ListenableFuture<String>> fList = ...

    fList.forEach(f -> Futures.addCallback(f, new FutureCallback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String resp) {
            resps.add(resp);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            // NOP
        }
    }));

    ListenableFuture<List<String>> f0 = Futures.successfulAsList(fList);

    Futures.addCallback(f0, new FutureCallback<List<String>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<String> r) {
            if (!result.hasResult()) {
                result.
                    if (r != null) {
                        result.setResult(...);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                // NOP
            }
        }); 

    return result;  
}
```

My code doesn't work because it waits for a result from all futures, but I need the fastest result with respect to DeferredResult timeout. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
DeferredResult<String> foo() {
  DeferredResult<String> result = new DeferredResult<>(3000L);

  List<ListenableFuture<String>> fList = ...

  ExecutorService serializingExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
  fList.forEach(
      f ->
          Futures.addCallback(
              f,
              new FutureCallback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String value) {
                  if (!result.hasResult()) {
                    result.setResult(value);
                  }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {}
              },
              // To avoid race in the callback:
              serializingExecutor));

  return result;
}
```

Comment: Please explain what this does. How have you achieved _I want to set the result for the first successful future in the list or if timeout didn't expire yet to get a successful result from all futures_? The call to `hasResult` is unnecessary. `setResult` returns `false` if the result has already been set.

Answer (score 0):

This does return wrapper object with list of results of Futures that managed to finish before timeout and indication whether all finished (`allFinished` property).

In your handling code you can then check whether all finished, and return the whole list or just a first item (or none, if no Future finished).

```
DeferredResult<ResultWrapper> foo() {
        DeferredResult<ResultWrapper> result = new DeferredResult<>(3000L);

        ListeningExecutorService executor = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3));
        List<ListenableFuture<String>> fList = IntStream.range(1, 1000)
                .mapToObj(i -> executor.submit(() -> String.valueOf(i))).collect(Collectors.toList());

        List<String> resps = Lists.newArrayListWithCapacity(fList.size());
        Object lock = new Object();

        fList.forEach(f -> Futures.addCallback(f, new FutureCallback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String resp) {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    resps.add(resp);
                    result.setResult(new ResultWrapper(
                            resps.size() == fList.size(), 
                            ImmutableList.copyOf(resps)));
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                // NOP
            }
        }));

        return result;
    }

    private static class ResultWrapper {

        private boolean allFinished;
        private List<String> list;

        public ResultWrapper(boolean allFinished, List<String> list) {
            this.allFinished = allFinished;
            this.list = list;
        }

        public boolean isAllFinished() {
            return allFinished;
        }

        public List<String> getList() {
            return list;
        }
    }
```